# angularJS $broadcast and $on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

is there a way to make the $broadcast propagate the variable to the $on during initialization phase?

```
<div ng-app='test'>
    <div ng-controller='testCtrl'> <span>{{testContent}}</span> 
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl2">
        <input type='text' ng-change="updateContent()" ng-model="testContent2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.factory('sharedContent', function ($rootScope) {
    var standardContent;
    var resizeProportion;
    return {
        setStandardContent: function (newStandardContent) {
            standardContent = newStandardContent;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('updateContent');
            console.log('broadcast');
        },
        getStandardContent: function () {
            return standardContent;
        },
        setResizeProportion: function (newResizeProportion) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('updateResizeProportion');
        },
    }
});
app.run(function (sharedContent) {
    sharedContent.setStandardContent('haha');
});

function testCtrl($scope, sharedContent) {
    $scope.testContent;
    $scope.$on('updateContent', function () {
        console.log('receive');
        $scope.testContent = sharedContent.getStandardContent();
    });
}

function testCtrl2($scope, sharedContent) {
    $scope.testContent2 = 'test';
    $scope.updateContent = function () {
        sharedContent.setStandardContent($scope.testContent2);
    };
}
```

Sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jiaming/NsVPe/

The span will display the value as the input changes, which is due to the ng-change function.

However, at initialization phase, the value "haha" was not propagated to the $scope.testContent and thus, nothing was shown at first runtime. Is there a way to make the value "haha" appear at the first runtime?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a little delay using `$timeout` function. Just update the code in the factory it will start working.

Please refer the code below for the factory:

```
app.factory('sharedContent', function ($rootScope,$timeout) {
    var standardContent;
    var resizeProportion;
    return {
        setStandardContent: function (newStandardContent) {
            standardContent = newStandardContent;
            $timeout(function(){
              $rootScope.$broadcast('updateContent');
            },0)
             console.log('broadcast');
        },
        getStandardContent: function () {
            return standardContent;
        },
        setResizeProportion: function (newResizeProportion) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('updateResizeProportion');
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the `ng-change` triggers upon subsequent changes to the model identified by `testContent2`. When the controller initializes, the value "test" is assigned to it. `ng-change` then keeps a track of subsequent changes - the initial assignment does not qualify for this, only subsequent changes do.

http://jsfiddle.net/vZwy4/ - I updated the fiddle provided by you. Here you can see that the `span` tag is correctly populated with the data.

What you needed to do was instead of using `ng-change`, you should use the scope's `$watch` functionality. So remove the `ng-change` directive from the input box and remove the `updateContent` method. Instead, replace it with the following code wherein you watch the changes to the `testContent2` model:

```
$scope.$watch('testContent2', function () {
    if ($scope.testContent2 === undefined || $scope.testContent2 === null) {
        return;
    }

    sharedContent.setStandardContent($scope.testContent2);

});
```

You can now see that the word "test" (I could not find anything to do with 'haha') appears the moment the page loads. Subsequent changes to the input are also updated in the `span`. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, i am actually looking for a way to initialize the span to the text "haha" at the first runtime of the application. I think the problem is that when the sharedContent.setStandardContent('haha') is called in app.run function, the controllers have not been created yet. And thus, the string 'haha' is not been populated to the span at first runtime. Is there any other method i could call to ensure that the string 'haha' is being populated to the span at first runtime?

Comment: @jiaming Why don't you set the value to "haha" inside TestCtrl2 itself instead of setting it to "test"?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are not taking into account that the `run` phase of the app gets executed **before** the controllers are initialized. Because broadcasted messages don't get buffered and are only served to the listeners that are listening in the moment the message is created, the `haha` value gets lost.

In your case, however, it's quite easy to make it work with a small change in your controller:

```
function testCtrl($scope, sharedContent) {
  updateTestContent();
  $scope.$on('updateContent', updateTestContent);

  function updateTestContent(){
     $scope.testContent = sharedContent.getStandardContent();
  }
}
```

I forked your JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/y3w5r01d/2/ where you can see on the console when each function (run and controllers) gets executed.